# syntax error: unexpected celsfah, expecting (

Tags: go, syntax

Hello I have a problem i searched but i didn't find the solution.
Can you help me please ?

```
if choix != 1 && choix != 2 {
  fmt.Println("you don't put a correct number!")
  continueProg=true
} else if choix == 1 {
  celsfah()
  fmt.Println("Celsius")
} else {
  //FahCels()
  fmt.Println("Fahrenheit")
}
```

I tried several solutions but none worked

The Function Celsfah

```
func celsfah(fahrenheit) {
celsius := 0
fahrenheit := 0
fmt.Println("Entrer une température en Celsius à convertir en Fahrenheit : ")
fmt.Scanln(&celsius)
fahrenheit = celsius*1.8+32
fmt.Println(&fahrenheit)
}
```

Comment: share your `celsfah()` func please.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've simplified your code a bit and fixed some issues to turn it into a running program. The main issues were:

- parameter into celsfah() unnecessary
- the final Println() statement was printing the pointer to fahrenheit instead of the value

`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  choix := 1

  if choix != 1 && choix != 2 { 
    fmt.Println("you didn't put in the correct number!")
  } else if choix == 1 { 
    celsfah()
    fmt.Println("Celsius")
  } else {
    //fahcels()
    fmt.Println("Fahrenheit")
  }
}

func celsfah() {
  celsius := 0.0 
  fahrenheit := 0.0 
  fmt.Println("Enter a temperature in Celsius to convert to Fahrenheit: ")
  fmt.Scanln(&celsius)
  fahrenheit = celsius*1.8 + 32
  fmt.Println(fahrenheit)
}
```

`

Comment: Thank You for your help but now i have these errors : .\convertisseurCelsiusFarenheit.go:46: syntax error: unexpected celsfah, expecting (
.\convertisseurCelsiusFarenheit.go:47: syntax error: unexpected celsius

Comment: Here is a link to the code above in [goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jagqe02lSo). Does this work for you? If yes, could you make the adjustments you'd like and post a link to your code back here?

Comment: your code works for me. There you have the code. https://play.golang.org/p/6nJnJGfLA4

Comment: You are simply missing a closing parentheses '}' at the end of your main function. Fixed here: [https://play.golang.org/p/agvgxOQLgl](https://play.golang.org/p/agvgxOQLgl)

Comment: Thank you man sorry for lose your time. How close this questions ?